# how call method varargs or (int...args) in main class giving arguments at command line

Tags: java

```
public class VarGreet {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

         printGreeting(args[0],args);
    }
    public static void printGreeting(String s, Integer...id) {
         for (Integer n : names) {
              System.out.println("Hello " + n + ". "); 
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: `args` is an array of `Strings` change --> `Integer...id` to `String...id`, where is `names` declared ?.  that aside what is the problem? what is your question? due to those reasons I am voting to close this question for "unclear what you're asking"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a String to an int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-a-string-to-an-int-in-java)

Comment: how could i pass input to Integer...id in main, when i call the PrintGreeting

Comment: Yah, my mistake it will id there not names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `printGreeting` you are looping over names (not `id`). Fix that first,

```
for (Integer n : id) {
    System.out.println("Hello " + n + ". ");
}
```

Then, assuming you are using Java 8+, you can start with the second argument and map everything to an `Integer`, collect that as a `List` and then convert that to an `Integer[]` like

```
printGreeting(args[0], Stream.of(args).skip(1).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)
        .boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()).toArray(new Integer[] {}));
```